# Microsoft Visual Basic Compile Error Method or Data Member Not Found

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have been working on a login system for my access database, the login system works fine but when i try to create a ACCDE it won't let me so based on the error I checked the code and vba gave me this error (Compile error: method or data member not found) when I compiled it, and help is appreciated. The code is below. Access says that this line is the error: (The Section With Stars Is The Found Error)[.txtLoginID]

`If IsNull(Me.txtLoginID) Then`

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim UserLevel As Integer
    Dim TempPass As String
    Dim ID As Integer

    If IsNull(Me.txtLoginID) Then
        MsgBox "Please Enter LoginID", vbInformation, "LoginID Required"
        Me.txtLoginID.SetFocus
    ElseIf IsNull(Me.txtpassword) Then
        MsgBox "Please Enter Password", vbInformation, "Password Required"
        Me.txtpassword.SetFocus
    Else
        'process the job
        If (IsNull(DLookup("UserLogin", "tblUser", "UserLogin='" & Me.txtLoginID.Value & "'"))) Or _
            (IsNull(DLookup("Password", "tblUser", "Password='" & Me.txtpassword.Value & "'"))) Then
            MsgBox "Incorrect LoginID or Password"
        Else
            UserLevel = DLookup("UserSecurity", "tblUser", "UserLogin = '" & Me.txtLoginID.Value & "'")
            TempPass = DLookup("password", "tblUser", "password = '" & Me.txtpassword.Value & "'")
            ID = DLookup("UserID", "tblUser", "UserLogin = '" & Me.txtLoginID.Value & "'")
            DoCmd.Close
            If (TempPass = "password") Then
                MsgBox "Please Change Your Password", vbInformation, "New Password Required"
                DoCmd.OpenForm "tblUser", , , "[UserID] = " & ID
            Else
                If UserLevel = 1 Then
                    'MsgBox "Login Sucussfull"
                    DoCmd.OpenForm "Admin Navigation Form"
                Else
                    If UserLevel = 2 Then
                        'MsgBox "Login Sucussfull"
                        DoCmd.OpenForm "Area Director Navigation Form"
                        If UserLevel = 2 Then
                            DoCmd.LockNavigationPane -1
                        Else
                            DoCmd.OpenForm "Area Director Navigation Form"
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: $20 says your form doesn't have a control named `txtLoginId`.

Comment: How would I add in a control for that would that be control source?

Comment: You wouldn't need a control source since you aren't saving it to any table.

Comment: Thats what i thought

Comment: So what does he mean by i don't have a control named?

Comment: There isn't a text field on your form that is called txtLoginId.

Answer (score 0):

Sure that the problem isn't on your main code.
When you try to compile any access application and create MDE/ACCDE application, you must verify your library and references.

Check on your VBA panel: TOOLS >> REFERENCES
And verify that you have all and haven't any line with: [ERROR] or [NOT FOUND]

Other possibility is that you are using DAO and ADO code and haven't referenced the library preferred. A Sample:
With ERROR: `dim db as database`
Correct: `dim db as dao.database`

Simply if you have some library problem or bad reference, the compilation process can't be completed and return an error over any part of code.